# How to tell if this is the last poll in spring integration cron triggers?

Tags: spring-integration

We are using cron based triggers in our file and db polling. Sometimes we like to know if this is the last poll or not. Is this something available in spring integration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "last" - last today?

It's not too hard to write a custom version of the `CronTrigger` to call `this.sequenceGenerator.next(...)` again with the new result to see if the next poll will be tomorrow.

The question is really what action do you want to take if that occurs? Only knowing it inside the trigger doesn't help very much; I guess you could set a boolean `lastToday` and test it elsewhere in your app.

Spring Integration 4.2 (currently at milestone 2) has [conditional pollers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) which would allow you to take some action after the last poll (as determined above) completes.

Comment: We have requirement where we poll for file every day between 9AM to 2PM every 30 sec. If file is not received for that day then we sent email at the end of polling to respected client. So idea is to check if it is last poll and we still did not received file then send email

Comment: A simpler solution would be to capture the time each time a file is processed; then, at 2pm check the last time and if it was yesterday, send the email.

Comment: Thank you Gary. We are doing that currently but wanted to see if there is any better solution or not.

Comment: The 4.2 conditional poller stuff will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only from the custom `Trigger` implementation. For example we often show `OnlyOnceTrigger`:

```
@Bean
public Trigger onlyOnceTrigger() {
    return new Trigger() {

        private final AtomicBoolean invoked = new AtomicBoolean();

        @Override
        public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
            return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
        }
    };
}
```

You can inject to your version the `ApplicationEventPublisher` and in case of the end for triggering (the next date as `null`) you emit some custom `ApplicationEvent`.

From other side you configure an `<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter>` for that event. And your Spring Integration application is ready to react for that!

Seems for me it's just enough to extend `CronTrigger` and invoke `super.nextExecutionTime()` for your case...